# Error while using imshow in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulation, imshow

I'm trying to make a traffic simulation with cars and signals using MATLAB. Where signals will control how many cars are present at a certain time. I'm just starting this function. Basically what I'm doing right now is trying to generate images of cars on the road. The code is given below and the comments explain the purpose of specific parts of the code. However there's something wrong with the 'imshow' function. Can someone point out the mistake I'm making? (All the files are placed in the current working directory)

Since I cant attach a picture here. I've uploaded them on Dropbox and the links are given below.

```
function [ output_args ] = drawcars( ncars )
%drawcars takes the number of cars at a timestep & shows an image for each car on the road.

image(imread('road.jpg'));         %load the road

% plot the number of cars
hold on;
for x=1:50:ncars*50
ih = image(imread('car.png'));
ih.XData = [x+5 x+50];             %to plot cars adjacent to one and another
ih.YData = [100 50];               %same line on the Y axis.
end
drawnow;
hold off;

pause(1);                          %wait for one second.
end
```

EDIT: Okay so I've fixed the Image processing toolbox. It isnt giving the desired output. It only shows one `car.png` placed on the top left corner of `road.jpg`.

The command line shows this for `drawcars(5)`.

```
Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2
Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details. 
> In drawcars at 12 
Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2
Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details. 
> In drawcars at 12 
Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2
Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details. 
> In drawcars at 12 
Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2
Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details. 
> In drawcars at 12 
Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2
Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details. 
> In drawcars at 12
```

*OUTPUT*
[image: THE OUTPUT]

Comment: Please, do not post code in images!!!!! Paste the code in the question

Comment: most likely you dont have image processing toolbox. Writte `ver` in your command line and see if one of the toolboxes listed is "image processing toolbox". If its not there, then thats the problem.

Comment: Oh okay sorry.
Its hard getting the code to paste in the correct format to make it easily readable so I decided to post an image.
Should I go ahead and paste the code?

Comment: Yeah! paste the code! And then format it as code pressing the {} in the editor! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: imshow is used when you already read the image data. So, instead of imshow('road.jpg'), you should use imshow(imread('road.jpg')). You have done this in your loop correctly

Comment: @Lati actually `imshow('road.jpg')` should work if the Image Processing Toolbox is installed. You can try using `imshow('peppers.png')` for instance.

Comment: As Ander mentioned, do you have the Image Processing Toolbox installed?

Comment: Ive added the code. However Ive checked and Image Processing toolbox is installed. Also imshow(imread('road.jpg')) isn't working either.

[Undefined function 'imshow' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.]
This error is shown if I use imshow(imread('road.jpg')).

Comment: What does `which imshow` return?

Comment: Can it have anything to do with the size of the images? Road.jpg is 800 x 465 pixels whereas car.png is 510 x 279 pixels.

Comment: @nkjt If I use `imshow(imread('road.jpg'))` instead of  `imshow('road.jpg') `as suggested by Lati it still gives an error. This time its `Undefined function 'imshow' for input arguments of type 'uint8'`.

Comment: That wasn't what I asked.  `which imshow` should show you if MATLAB can find the function at all.  It's possible your toolbox isn't properly installed or the path to the Image Processing Toolbox is wrong.

Comment: I think theres something wrong with the Image Processing Toolbox. If I write imshow for any image placed in the current working directory it gives an error `Undefined function 'imshow' for input arguments of type 'char'.`

Im doing an online course and is it possible that the license they gave has limited features such that Im unable to use the Image Processing Toolbox?

Comment: Do you have a **variable** called `imshow` in your workspace?  Type in `clear imshow`, then try your code again.

Comment: Nope its not that either. Theres something wrong with Image Processing Toolbox. Programs that ran properly earlier are not running now. I recently upgraded MATLAB.

Comment: @bluescreenofdeath - That's very odd.  Try reinstalling MATLAB and if that doesn't help, contact MathWorks support.

Comment: @Benoit_11, Indeed it works, so far I always loaded the image first before show it. then it seems Matlab is confused with the function "imshow". I would reinstall the Matlab as rayryeng suggested

Comment: Okay so I reinstalled it and its working now but it isnt giving the desired output. Should I post another question and post the error message along with it?

Comment: I've edited the question itself. Please take a look.

Comment: @AnderBiguri pls take a look